# Assign multiple event handlers to single event

Tags: javascript

I want to assign a JavaScript function to an event that already has a handler function. The new function should not change or remove (unassign) the existing function.

As an example:

I have a function called `exFunction()` that is already assigned to `document.onmousemove`. I have another function `newFun()` to assign to the same event. What I want to happen is when the `document.onmousemove` event occurs both functions are triggered.

`newFun()` is not a static function. It is going to be **changing** according to the webpage. (otherwise I can just write another function that calls both functions).

**pure JavaScript only**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `addEventListener`, you can apply multiple functions.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', exFunction)
document.addEventListener('mousemove', newFun)
```

Comment: So It wont be replacing previous function

Comment: @VikumDheemantha If you want to change the handler dynamically look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
myFunction();
someother();
```

});

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, you can easily assign several eventListeners to the event.
Note that the name of the function is the address of the code to execute and this address is immutable. The snippet shows what works and what doesn't.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div');

function foo1(e) {
  console.log('foo1');
  if (e.altKey)
    foo1 = foo2; //this doesn't work
};

function foo2(e) {
  console.log('foo2');
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    myDiv.removeEventListener('click', foo2);
    myDiv.addEventListener('click', foo3);
  }
};

function foo3(e) {
  console.log('foo3');
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    myDiv.removeEventListener('click', foo3);
    myDiv.addEventListener('click', foo2);
  }
};
//assign **addresses** of functions to eventListener
myDiv.addEventListener('click', foo1);
myDiv.addEventListener('click', foo2);
```

```html
<div id="my-div" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:solid 1px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` is the right way to do this however time to time you may need to do this over the DOM element property event listeners by monkey patching.

Forgive me for partially snatching @AlexKudryashev's snippet.

```js
var myDiv       = document.getElementById('my-div'),
    myBut       = document.getElementById('my-button'),
    f1          = e => console.log(`clicked "${e.currentTarget.id}" and f1 invoked`);
    f2          = e => console.log(`clicked "${e.currentTarget.id}" and f2 invoked`);
    monkeyPatch = (f1,f2) => e => (f1(e),f2(e));

myDiv.onclick = f1;
myBut.onclick = function(e){
                  console.log(`f2 monkey patched to f1. Click My Div to see the effect`);
                  myDiv.onclick = monkeyPatch(myDiv.onclick, f2);
                }
```

```html
<div id="my-div" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:solid 1px">My Div</div>
<button id="my-button">Monkey Patch f2</button>
```